# Is there a well understood algorithm or solution model for this meeting scheduling scenario?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I  have a complex problem and I want to know if an existing and well understood solution model exists or applies, like the Traveling Salesman problem.

**Input**:

- A calendar of N time events, defined by starting and finishing time, and place.
- The capacity of each meeting place (maximum amount of people it can simultaneously hold)
- A set of pairs `(Ai,Aj)` which indicates that attendant `Ai` wishes to meet with attendat `Aj`, and `Aj` accepted that invitation.

**Output**:

- For each assistant `A`, a cronogram of all the events he will attend. The main criteria is that each attendants should meet as many of the attendants who accepted his invites as possible, satisfying the space constraints.

So far, we thought of solving with backtracking (trying out all possible solutions), and using linear programming (i.e. defining a model and solving with the simplex algorithm)

**Update:** If `Ai` already met `Aj` in some event, they don't need to meet anymore (they have already met).

Comment: Can more than two people meet together at once, or is this a one-on-one meeting?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_allocation  This meets the criteria for a class of algorithms: auction class I believe.

Comment: The fact that each meeting place can hold multiple people suggests that you can have multiple people meeting at once.

Comment: google for "timetabling algorithm"

Comment: @MichaelSlade are you sure timetabling is close enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @SaeedAmiri, this looks like a complex problem.

My guess would be that the *backtracking* and *linear programming* options you are considering will explode as soon as the number of assistants grows a bit (maybe in the order of tens of assistants).

Maybe you should consider a  (meta)heuristic approach if optimality is not a requirement, or constraint programming to build an initial model and see how it scales.

To give you a more precise answer, why do you need to solve this problem? what would be the typical number of attendees? number of rooms?

Comment: Using an heuristic seems reasonable, since this problems seems to be NP-hard. I'm looking into those but still can't devise a good one. The attendants are in the order of the hundreds, rooms in the order of tens, and events take between 1-3 hours throughout 1 month.

Comment: I think you are facing quite a big problem, if you consider it from a practical perspective I would suggest you start by designing a constructive heuristic able to build a feasible solution.
Then I think large neighborhood search ([LNS](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.156.2703&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) would be a good start as its implementation is quite straight forward: for a given number of iteration you will remove meetings from your schedule, and then try to reinsert them.

Comment: We ended up implementing an ad-hoc heuristic, I wouldn't know if it fits the LNS category. The graph theory-based answer by @Saeed Amiri looked promising, but we just didn't have time to catch up on the theory. Our solution runs in the order of milliseconds for the given problem size, and seemed to scale pretty well for bigger sizes, though we didn't test that too thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is as hard as [minimum maximal matching problem](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node21.html) in interval graphs, w.l.o.g Assume capacity of rooms is `2` means they can handle only one meeting in time. You can model your problem with [Interval graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph), each interval (for each people) is one node. Also edges are if A_i & A_j has common time and also they want to see each other, set weight of edges to the amount of time they should see each other, . If you find the minimum maximal matching in this graph, you can find the solution for your restricted case. But notice that this graph is n-partite and also each part is interval graph.

P.S: note that if the amount of time that people should be with each other is fixed this will be more easier than weighted one.

Comment: I added a constraint to the problem. Could you show a small example of how to setup the graph from the input data? In the meantime, I'll try to get my head around the theory of minimum maximal matching (I had discrete math -graph theory- classes in uni but this goes beyond that).

Comment: @dario_ramos, I modeled your restricted version  with graph(I relaxed your problem), this is not so hard, First set possible intervals as nodes of graphs, then connect two node if they are belong to two different people which should see each other and their related interval has some overlaps. Do it upto this part, and if you have a good intuition on it, I'll say more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a good MIP solver (cplex/gurobi via acedamic initiative, but coin OR and LP_solve are open-source, and not bad either), I would definitely give simplex a try. I took a look at formulating your problem as a mixed integer program, and my feeling is that it will have pretty strong relaxations, so branch and cut and price will go a long way for you. These solvers give remarkably scalable solutions nowadays, especially the commercial ones. Advantage is they also provide an upper bound, so you get an idea of solution quality, which is not the case for heuristics.

Formulation:

Define z(i,j) (binary) as a variable indicating that i and j are together in at least one event n in {1,2,...,N}. 
Define z(i,j,n) (binary) to indicate they are together in event n. 
Define z(i,n) to indicate that i is attending n. 
Z(i,j) and z(i,j,m) only exist if i and j are supposed to meet.

For each t, M^t is a subset of time events that are held simulteneously. 
So if event 1 is from 9 to 11, event 2 is from 10 to 12 and event 3 is from 11 to 13, then
M^1 = {event 1, event 2) and M^2 = {event 2, event 3}. I.e. no person can attend both 1 and 2, or 2 and 3, but 1 and 3 is fine.

```
Max sum Z(i,j)                      

z(i,j)<= sum_m z(i,j,m)   
(every i,j)(i and j can meet if they are in the same location m at least once)

z(i,j,m)<= z(i,m)   (for every i,j,m) 
(if i and j attend m, then i attends m)

z(i,j,m)<= z(j,m)     (for every i,j,m) 
(if i and j attend m, then j attends m)

sum_i z(i,m) <= C(m)   (for every m) 
(only C(m) persons can visit event m)

sum_(m in M^t) z(i,m) <= 1  (for every t and i)  
(if m and m' are both overlapping time t, then no person can visit them both. )
```

Comment: Good thing about LPSolve is that they have a very good yahoo community. BTW, what is the size of your problem?

Comment: The attendants are in the order of the hundreds, rooms in the order of tens, and events take between 1-3 hours throughout 1 month